# Probability of Finding a state

Tags: radiation, probability

### Question:

Given the ODE: $$\frac{dN}{dt}=-\frac{N(t)}{\kappa}.$$
This represents the rate of decay of some hydrogen to its ground state. Let at $t=0$ the object has not decayed. Now we are talking about the unique solution to the ODE:
$$N(t) = N_0e^{-\frac{t}{\kappa}}.$$
How do I find the probability of the hydrogen dropping to its ground state happening at any given $t$?

### My Answer:

Well, a probability would be normalized so I normalize it:
$$\int^{\infty}_{0}dt N(t) = 1\\
\Rightarrow N_0 = \frac{1}{\kappa}.$$

Can I represent the probability of finding the hydrogen decayed at $t$ by the function: 
$$N(t) = \frac{e^{-\frac{t}{\kappa}}}{\kappa}?$$

Comment: No, $N_0$ is simply the number of H atoms at $t=0$. The number of H atoms decayed by time $t$ is $N_0-N(t)$.

Comment: okay, but how do I find a probability function with $N(t)$?

Comment: The probability of *which event*, exactly?

Comment: The probability of the Hydrogen dropping into its lower energy state. $N(t)$ represents the rate of decay.

Comment: By decay I mean the act of dropping into the ground state.

Comment: @Gert this doesn't make sense. If probabilities couldn't be calculated for stochastic processes, QM would lose its point.